# HAProxy doesn't automatically reload DNS

Tags: haproxy, internal-dns, amazon-route53, debian-stretch

I've installed HAProxy 1.7.5-2 on a Debian Stretch (9) for a blue/green deployment infrastructure.

HAProxy is setup in TCP mode and reloads DNS every 5 seconds but it doesn't.

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 warning
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 10m
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

# Default SSL material locations
ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
crt-base /etc/ssl/private

# Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
# For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
#  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
# An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
#  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    log     global
    mode    tcp
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 360s
    timeout client  300s
    timeout server  300s
    retries         99999

resolvers aws-vpc-dns
    nameserver vpc     {DNSIP}:53
    resolve_retries    30
    timeout retry      1s
    hold valid         5s

frontend site-frontend
    bind *:80
    use_backend site-backend

backend site-backend
    balance roundrobin
    server company-www target.services.company.com resolvers aws-vpc-dns

listen blue-webapp-http
    bind :9000
    balance roundrobin
    server company-blue blue.services.company.com resolvers aws-vpc-dns
```

When I change the DNS record to something else, the `host` command on the HAProxy server returns the new addresses correctly.

Reloading/restarting HAProxy service is the only way I've found for now.

Any clue on what could be the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hostname used for `server` is resolved during `haproxy` startup when configuration file is parsed or during health checks. You don't have any checks defined for your `server` so you can get updated hostname only during restart/reload. If you want `server` hostname to be updated at runtime you need to define health checks.

See HAProxy documentation [Server IP address resolution using DNS](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#5.3) for details.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!
Do you know why if I set `target.services.company.com` to google.com for example, I receive 502 Bad Gateway (HAProxy is behind a load balancer)

Comment: Per https://www.haproxy.com/blog/dns-service-discovery-haproxy/ switching to HAProxy 1.8 also allows DNS resolution to happen at runtime irrespective to health checks.